# Специфика работы   Rewrite

Tags: apache, apache-modules, mod_rewrite, apache2.2

есть путь

> http://www.example.ru/index.php/news/index

нужно переделать в

> http://example.ru/news

и любые другие варианты, например

> http://example.ru/

т.е без индекс.

и еще, в процесе попыток сделать все самому, браузеры стали странно себя вести. rewrite вернул в исходное состаяние, а сайт работает по прежнему не так. кеш?

то что есть.

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule . index.php

что значит $1 в RewriteRule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php/news/index$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ news [R=301,L]
```

Либо вариант без условия:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php/news/index$ news [NC,R=301,L]
```

Для любых других вариантов (правило идущее следом):

```
RewriteRule ^index.*$ / [R=301,L]
```

> что значит $1 в RewriteRule?

Это POSIX стандарт регулярных выражений, который декларирует, что найденная подстрока хранится в массиве-результате RegExp-поиска и может быть использована для последующей подстановки. Собственно, в правилах RewriteRule используется данный стандарт.

Пример вышеприведённого привал с выделением подстроки:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(news)/index$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Почитайте про регулярные выражения:

- [RegExp JS](http://javascript.ru/RegExp);
- [Регулярные выражения (Wiki)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

> ...а сайт работает по прежнему не так. кеш?

Бывает и такое. Очистка кэша браузера помогает не всегда. Рекомендую закрывать браузер, или как дополнительная мера, перезапустить web-сервер.

Comment: нет, не работает.

Comment: сайт на yii

Comment: Листинг `.htaccess` можете показать (можно разместить тут [pastebin][1])?

Возможно, Вы забыли включить `mod_rewrite`:

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    #условия и правила
    
    </IfModule> 

  [1]: http://pastebin.com/