# Специфика работы rewrite. Как настроить склейку под Yii и убрать index.php? + Добавить слеш?

Tags: apache, apache-modules, mod_rewrite, yii, apache2.2

есть url

```
http://www.example.ru/index.php/
http://www.example.ru/index.php
http://www.example.ru/
http://www.example.ru
http://example.ru/index.php/
http://example.ru/index.php
```

нужно переделать его в такой

```
http://example.ru/
```

чтобы убрать индекс для yii, использовал такой .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

чтобы сделать склейку, нагуглил такое решение

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursite.org(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yoursite.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

как можно совместить это в месте? и как можно добавить слеш в конец ко всем запросам или убрать?
з.ы важно чтобы подключались css и js файлы в yii/

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` должен быть такой:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on

# если директория или файл существуют, использовать их напрямую
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# иначе отправлять запрос на файл index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Далее в `/protected/config/main.php` пишем такие строки:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
          /* rules here... */
    ),
),
```

Слеш в конце вроде как сам добавляется.

Comment: у меня это всё уже есть. проблема в том что я могу зайти на сайт http://www.example.ru/index.php/ и http://example.ru/ так, а должно быть только так http://example.ru/

Comment: 301 редирект

Comment: А зачем скрывать `index.php` если не секрет? У вас ведь все ссылки будут в формате http://mysite.ru/home/index ?

Comment: чпу, требование заказчика. с home/index я сделал в rules редирект на home

Comment: @Python_Pro 

> А зачем скрывать index.php если не секрет?

Не SEO-шно, как и префикс www.

Comment: @romeo почему? помоему, как раз для SEO и делаеться.

Comment: @ferz9 Это я не Вам, а Python_Pro. Вы всё верно говорите.

Answer (score 0):

Я Вам уже привёл [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/188217/apache-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-rewrite). Если собрать вместе, то получится так:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Убираем www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php/news/.*$ news [NC,R=301,L]

#любые другие конструкции ведут к корню
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index.*$ / [NC,R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Убрать слэш:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Добавить слэш:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)(html|php|htm)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: слеш уходит, если добавить {www.example.org/index.php/} результат {http://example.org/http:/example.org/http:/example.org/index.php/example.org/index.php} 
{www.} тоже уходит, только перестают работать все ссылки на сайте. 
{index.php} всё ещё остаёться.
{news} уже не нужен, я сделал его через роутер.

Comment: прошлый я задал не достаточно коректно.